# Is there any creature or being with the role of keeping good and evil balanced?

Tags: myth-identification, comparative, mythical-creatures, folklore

Is there any creature or being in either mythology or folklore that serves as a form of "negotiator" between good and evil, with the role of keep order and balance between them
(whether it's by exterminating the more powerful side or by any other means)?

I don't have a specific type of mythology or folklore in mind, just wondering if there are any at all.